# Variadic Function that converts any type to string

Tags: c++, string, variadic-functions

I'm trying to use generics and varargs in c++ to make a method that accepts any stringable type and concatenates it into a single string.

An example of the functionality i'm looking for is

stringify(50, 5000.00, "test") and the result should be "505000.00test".

Comment: What mechanism do you want to use for stringifying a single component?

Comment: Are you abel to use c++17?

Comment: I'm not able to use c++17 unfortunately. I don't have a preference however It needs to be able to support multiple types. Also this will be called many many times and needs to be fast as it can be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [C++17 fold-expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), [`to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) (in lieu of the heavier iostreams), and [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using std::to_string;
auto to_string(std::string s) noexcept { return std::move(s); }

template <class... T>
auto stringify(T&&... x)
-> decltype((std::string() + ... + to_string(x))) {
    return (std::string() + ... + to_string(x));
}
```

Fusing the advantages of ubiquitous implementation of stream-inserters with the advantage of `to_string()`s generally much better Performance, where it works at all:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <sstream>

namespace detail {
    using std::to_string;
    auto to_string(std::string s) noexcept { return std::move(s); }

    template <class... T>
    auto stringify(int, T&&... x)
    -> decltype((std::string() + ... + to_string(x))) {
        return (std::string() + ... + to_string(x));
    }

    template <class... T>
    auto stringify(long, T&&... x)
    -> decltype((std::declval<std::ostream&>() << ... << x), std::string()) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        (ss << ... << x);
        return ss.str();
    }
}

template <class... T>
auto stringify(T&&... x)
-> decltype(detail::stringify(1, x...)) {
    return detail::stringify(1, x...);
}
```

Comment: Concerning performance, note that `std::to_string` is bound to observe the current locale, so it's not necessarily the most efficient method either. In a quick test here on my machine, it was about 2× faster than `std::ostringstream`. However, `std::to_string` can only deal with arithmetic types. You'll have to add overloads to support other types yourself. It also won't support any formatting options. It's a tradeoff worth considering. If you do, note that terse function template syntax is not C++17 and that the trailing return type will be wanting to be wrapped in an additional pair of `()`…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Fixed that, and added more complicated code for using the probably most efficient solution which works.

Comment: This is a great answer! Unfortunately I can't use c++17 as of right now but I will accept this as an answer for people who may need something similar in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use an [std::ostringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and a C++17 fold expression to do just that:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Args>
std::string stringify(Args&&... args)
{
    std::ostringstream str;
    (str << ... << args);
    return str.str();
}
```

[live example here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Csstream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0Astd::string+stringify(Args%26%26...+args)%0A%7B%0A++++std::ostringstream+str%3B%0A++++(str+%3C%3C+...+%3C%3C+args)%3B%0A++++return+str.str()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aauto+test()%0A%7B%0A++++return+stringify(42,+%22asdf%22,+1.25f)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:61.03853690398432,l:'4',m:63.29866270430906,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:36.70133729569094,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:61.03853690398432,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:38.96146309601568,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

This will be able to concatenate any bunch of things that support an `operator <<` for standard formatted stream output into an `std::string`…

If you want to be able to use a call to this function in expression SFINAE, you could modify the signature to be

```
template <typename... Args>
auto stringify(Args&&... args) -> decltype((std::declval<std::ostream>() << ... << args), std::declval<std::ostringstream>().str());
```

Comment: You don't support SFINAE, and `std::ostringstream` is quite heavy-weight. On the other hand, lots of custom types support stream-insertion.

Comment: @Deduplicator If SFINAE support is really something one would feel a need for here, it could be added of course. I added a remark on how that could be done to my answer above. If the question is about turning arbitrary stuff into strings, then we're hopefully not talking about performance-critical territory to begin with. I would consider it far more likely that OP is looking for a general solution than worried about performance. And, as you point out yourself, the simple approach above is able to take advantage of any standard facilities for formatted output that may exist for a given type…